# Unity: OnCollisionEnter fires only on NEW entry, but not on NEW entry on different object with same name

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a platformer with appearing boxes. The box gets rendered as soon as the player hits it hitbox. This works just fine like so:

```
public class AppearingBoxes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Block, RageFace;

    bool showBlock = false;

    void Start()
    {
        showBlock = false;
    }


    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Birdy") 
        {
            showBlock = true;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Block.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = showBlock;
        RageFace.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = showBlock;
    }
}
```

This script is attached to all of those boxes. Each box is an individual box but all with the same script and properties and name:

[image]

But here comes the issue. Only the first HIT triggers a box. As you can imagine, the player jumps on top of those invisble boxes and then triggers the one he hits. The player now moves forward over the other boxes that are still invisble and enters there hitboxes. However they dont appear. I believe this is due to the fact that the player is still in the "same" hitbox even though it is a different prefab object. If I jump ontop of the invisible platform and then fall back down to it (i left and then reentered the trigger) the box on which I land immeadiately appears as it should.

So what can I do to get the box to appear as soon as the player touched it even though he is has not left the hitbox of the box before?

Thank you! :)

Comment: are `Block` and `RageFace` assigned to their corresponding `gameobjects` while you are in the game?

Comment: and why you dont just set `Renderer` to true in your if statement and use `FixedUpdate`? you can just write  `if (col.gameObject.name == "Birdy") 
        {
          Block.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true
        }
    }`

Comment: Hello, yes they are all ofcourse assigned. if they werent, they wouild simply not show up no matter if I jump on them or not. But they do show up but unfortunately only after entering their hitbox the second time. Also, I am doing this in fixedUpdate because just checking for the collision had a bit of a delay in them which I got around doing it like so ...

Comment: It makes no sense that a delay caused by directly enabling the renderer is eliminated by calling it even later using `FixedUpdate` ^^

Comment: Also note that using your script without changing anything [worked for me](https://imgur.com/a/JnxEKre) with a very basic setup of `BoxCollider2D` and `RigidBody2D` (just for testing I made some of the AppearingBoxes seperated, others overlapping and used different heights) -> no problem

Comment: @derHugo It worked for you? I tried the same it did not work for me i got the `Script error` when i used `OnCollisionEnter`

Comment: @AliKanat ok without `OnCollisionEnter` but `OnCollisionEnter2D` otherwise it wouldn't work **at all** as already said .. not only the second time

Comment: @derHugo yeah i understood that point i was just curious if i did something different.

Comment: Sorry, It is supposed to say: Enter2D. It was a typo. However, still my problem persists :(

Comment: @derHugo also I am not using RBs on my blocks. I did and set their mass to 0 (or they woudl fall) but that didnt change anything. Still the blocks are invisble until I jump on them ...

Comment: use `RigidBody2D` on them and set it to `static` also check the Collision type as well .. might have to be dynamic at least on the player

Comment: @derHugo thanks but I solved it. check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone, I did find a "workaround" It sill doesnt really explain the issue but alreast works...

What I did was to increase the size of the BoxCollider for every box just a little bit more. Like 3 pixels bigger than the actual box the player stands on. This solved the issue but makes me wonder: If the player didnt "really" collide with the collider in the first place he wouldve fallen through. But he didnt. Now the colliders a slightly bigger and everything gets triggered just perfect. Maybe a bug in the engine?

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

- Try to change the boxes colliders to isTrigger and use instead OnTriggerEnter2D
- Or maybe it's because you use OnCollisionEnter instead of OnCollisionEnter2D ?

Comment: I don't think this is only a typo since OP claims it to work when entering the second time ... in your case it wouldn't work at all

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my code. Ofc it is OnEnter2D. Also changing them to triggers didnt change anything :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your code. I don't know if you missed that or it is a typo but you can not use `OnCollisionEnter` with a `Collision2D` parameter. Your game would run but it must be giving you this error message:

```
Script error: OnCollisionEnter
This message parameter has to be of type: Collision
The message will be ignored.
```

Use `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Birdy") 
    {
        showBlock = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is only a typo since OP claims it to work when entering the second time ... in your case it wouldn't work at all

Comment: thanks, but that was just a typo. it said Enter2D. Otherwise Unity would give me errors :)

Answer (score 0):

He didn't fall because the collider isn't Trigger that's all.